# From JQuery Mobile to PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a JQuery mobile app. I now want to deploy it natively to Android and iOS. To assist with this, I thought I would use PhoneGap. When I run my app, none of the styling information appears. There are no errors in the console window. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Are there any guides on going from JQuery mobile to phone gap? Everything I see starts with Phone Gap and builds from there. Am I doing this in reverse?

Thank you for any insistence. I really want to get this app onto Android and iOS. I feel like I'm so close. But I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you,

Comment: have you copied the js and css files witj images locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but you have something like this in your code?

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
```

If so that's wrong and you need to store your css locally in the assets folder if you want it to run locally within your WebView.

Otherwise, I'd suggest that you first run an 'hello world' on phone gap, and style just one element through an external local stylesheet (without worry about javascript for now). That's essentially the most difficult part, knowing where to put the file and how to reference it, so you do not want to confuse yourself with the extraneous code of your current project when you're learning that part.

Once you've figured that part out, it will be trivial for you to do the same with the jQuery Mobile library, both the css one and the js one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you include properly?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
```

put the .js file and .css file in the jquery.mobile folder.

But if you are using eclipse then you can create phonegap app directly.

I hope it would be helpful for you.

[image]